# How to disable Google QR scanner wizard in the unity SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

In my app i have noticed that in each installation, a screen by google pops up after launch and request access to the camera to scan the QR code of the cardboard.

Is there a way to programmatically disable this wizard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Cardboard.cs and BaseVRDevice scripts there are functions by the name of `ShowSettingsDialog`, `LaunchSettingsDialog`, and in the case of ios, `LaunchOnBoardingDialog`. These are the functions that call the opening of the scanner. I commented them out from being called in their scripts and called them on my own when the user wants to pair with cardboard.

Comment: Too bad you got downvoted, because that's the way to do it.